# Typescript : Generic type checking and child usability

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

In a method with a generic type, I would like to discern the object in order to cast it and call a method of a child class.

I have classes (User, Address, ...) that extend from the "BaseModel" class.
I have a repository class that use a generic type T extends BaseModel.

In these repositories, I would like to call a "fromJson" function from the child classes.
Either by a T.fromJson , or by trying to check the type of object with a switch, or any other possibilities ...

```
export class RepositoryService<T extends BaseModel> {
 constructor(protected api: ApiService) {}

 findById(id: number): Observable<T> {
   return this.api.findById(id).pipe(
     map((o) => {
       // return T.fromJson(o);
       // OR
       // switch(T) {
       //   case User:
       //     return User.fromJson(o);
       //   case Address:
       //     return Address.fromJson(o);
       // }
     })
   );
 }
}
```

But that 2 ways does not work.

How can I do this successfully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The typescript annotations like `T` do not exist at runtime, so you cannot use `T` to determine the type.  However, you can use the constructor to inject a reference to the class that this `RepositoryService` is for.

These types might not be quite right, but hopefully this puts you on the right path:

```
interface JsonConstructable<T> {
  fromJson(json: string): T;
}

export class RepositoryService<T extends BaseModel> {

 constructor(protected api: ApiService, private readonly modelClass: JsonConstructable<T>) {}

 findById(id: number): Observable<T> {
   return this.api.findById(id).pipe(
     map((o) => {
       this.modelClass.fromJson(o);
     })
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! 
In fact this repository is not for a modelclass but precisely to generate this model. So I can't pass it as constructor parameter :/

Comment: You would pass a reference to the class itself, not an instance of the class.  I thought you had a `User` class?  Or am I misreading this? *"I have classes (User, Address, ...) that extend from the "BaseModel" class"*

Comment: Yes I have it. How could I just pass a reference to the class ? That does not work when I just pass "User" for exemple, in class UserRepository extends RepositoryService<User>, i can't do in the constructor super(api, User); --> What should I do ?

Comment: Right so I'm talking about composition / dependency injection rather than inheritance.  You'll only have one `RepositoryService` class, but you'll have an *instance* for each model.  The type `T` for each instance corresponds to the model.  `const UserRepository = new RepositoryService(api, User)` should create an object `UserRepository` with the type `RepositoryService<User>`.